# How do you use UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

The [documentation of UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator) isn't very detailed. It implies that you may want to implement this protocol in rare circumstances, but `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` implements `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext`, which means that you have to implement over a dozen(!) methods to conform to the protocol. I've seen some other people using it by accessing the `transitionCoordinator` property of a UIViewController while it is being presented, usually in `viewWillAppear`. However, the documentation implies that `viewWillAppear` is not the right place to implement either. How are you supposed to make use of this protocol and synchronize animations with those of a presenting view?